# How to get a subset of items from a list in an AsyncNotifierProvider in Riverpod 2.0?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have recently started using Riverpod 2.0 but I'm constantly running into the following issue / limitation which I dont know how to solve neatly. I will illustrate this using the code from the docs as found on the [Riverpod 2.0 Docs for the NotifierProvider](https://docs-v2.riverpod.dev/docs/providers/notifier_provider).

The `AsyncTodosNotifier` contains a state with a list of `Todo` items, all of which have their fields. Now lets suppose I want to have a screen with just a list of all completed Todos. How can I accomplish this in a provider, rather than push this code to the `build` method of the widget. The latter not being reusable, not easily testable and not optimized in rendering.

Here the code that accomplishes the task. But the filtering happens within the `.when()` in the `build` method, which is not the place I would like this to happen

```dart
@immutable
class Todo {
  const Todo({
    required this.id,
    required this.description,
    required this.completed,
  });

  factory Todo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Todo(
      id: map['id'] as String,
      description: map['description'] as String,
      completed: map['completed'] as bool,
    );
  }

  // All properties should be `final` on our class.
  final String id;
  final String description;
  final bool completed;
}

class AsyncTodosNotifier extends AsyncNotifier<List<Todo>> {
  Future<List<Todo>> _fetchTodo() async {
    final json = await http.get('api/todos');
    final todos = jsonDecode(json) as List<Map<String, dynamic>>;
    return todos.map((todo) => Todo.fromJson(todo)).toList();
  }

  @override
  Future<List<Todo>> build() async {
    return _fetchTodo();
  }

// ... several CRUD methods
}

final asyncTodosProvider =
    AsyncNotifierProvider<AsyncTodosNotifier, List<Todo>>(() {
  return AsyncTodosNotifier();
});

class TodoListView extends ConsumerWidget {
  const TodoListView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final asyncTodos = ref.watch(asyncTodosProvider);

    return asyncTodos.when(
      data: (todos) => ListView(
        children: todos.map(
          (todo) {
            if (todo.completed) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(todo.description),
              );
            } else {
              return Container();
            }
          },
        ).toList(),
      ),
      loading: () => const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
      error: (err, stack) => Text('Error: $err'),
    );
  }
}
```

My goal is to have a second `AsyncNotifierProvider` or `FutureProvider` which re-uses the data fetched by the main `AsyncNotifierProvider` which will hold the state of all items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got some help from the Riverpod Discord server.

The answer is to setup another provider that listens to the `.future` value of the original `AsyncNotifierProvider`.

So in this case:

```dart
// Original (full) list
final asyncTodosProvider =
    AsyncNotifierProvider<AsyncTodosNotifier, List<Todo>>(() {
  return AsyncTodosNotifier();
});

// Filtered List
final completedTodosProvider = FutureProvider<List<Todo>>(
  (ref) async {
    final todos = await ref.watch(asyncTodosProvider.future);
    return todos.where((e) => e.isCompleted).toList();
  },
);
```